# Windows window docking

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm wondering how to dock / snap a window to the side of the screen in Windows, preferably with straight Win32 API. The effect I'm looking for is like the task bar -- a window that has a reserved space on screen, so that maximizing another window makes that window take up the rest of the screen, but leaves my window in place and visible.

I know various IM clients do this, but haven't been able to find any resources on how to do it. Not sure what the appropriate name for it is either.

Edit: "Application Desktop Toolbar" is the search term to use to find info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUYC you're looking for an app bar (MS-officially "Application Desktop Toolbar"). You can indeed create these with the Windows API.

Answer (score 3):

"App Bar" - you turn a window into an App Bar by sending the ABM_NEW message. Examples on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134206