# How to change accessible area of the desktop in Java?

Tags: java, windows, desktop

Is it possible to do so? My problem is opposite to [How to detect the available part of the main display that's available for normal windows ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315650/how-to-detect-the-available-part-of-the-main-display-thats-available-for-normal). I want to occupy some area and tell the system that available area is now less than it was...

EDIT: I really dug in the wrong direction... Solution of my problem here: [Windows window docking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476152/windows-window-docking)

Comment: Using just core Java? No, then this can't be done.

Comment: May be Win32 API has such functionality and use it via JNI?

Comment: Please explain when downvoting, people. I don't think this is a particularly bad question.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi: I'm not the down-voter, but perhaps it's just folks sorry for the poor users of cybersoft's program.

Comment: Yes cybersoft, JNI and JNA could certainly do something like this. You would need to look into the windows API at msdn for details.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, why do you think so? Anyway, I'm not going to distribute, I want to use it for personal purposes

Comment: Hmm, docs are very huge. Where I must search?

Comment: I cant find this functions!